# How to make JSFiddle of sprites using THREE.JS source and image files from Github?

Tags: javascript, html, image, three.js

Hi I am trying to make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5fmvge5/11/) based on the official THREE.js [HUD Sprites example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_sprites).

The JSFiddle runs but it doesn't seem to load/apply the sprite images using the URL's in the original file:-

```
//... URL's as in the Original file
var mapA = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ("textures/sprite0.png", undefined, createHUDSprites );

var mapB = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture     ("textures/sprite1.jpg" );

mapC = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture         ( "sprite2.png" );
```

I have tried various alternative URL's without success:-

```
//... my failed URL attempts
/*
var mapA =THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/textures/sprite0.png", undefined, createHUDSprites );

var mapB = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture     ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/textures/sprite1.jpg" );

mapC = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ("http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/blob/master/examples/textures/sprite2.png" );
```

I realize there is a problem trying to access image files from a different origin (the Cross Origin Resource Sharing - CORS- issue) but I had hoped to be able to find both the THREE.js library and the example images on the same server.  I guess that Github is not designed to act as a live file server, at least for images.  I suppose I could simply copy the library and images to my own web site and link to that when I raise questions in StackOverflow - but surely that is the sort of thing that JSFiddle is supposed to be for?

So my question - is there any way technically of accessing the images used in the THREE.js examples and the THREE.js library from the same (official) origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it by loading the images.
But, you can use the image data (dataUri) in a variable.

```
var imageData = "data:image/png;base64,...."
var mapA = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imageData)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5fmvge5/13/

I used this tool to get the image dataUri.
http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

Comment: Nice solution, many thanks. I have added the other two sprites in the same way in this updated [JSFiddle ](https://jsfiddle.net/y5fmvge5/16/).